# Does bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_xyz_function_surface() modify an existing mesh or create a new one?

Tags: mesh

Does the Blender add-on script for `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_xyz_function_surface()` modify an existing mesh or create a new one?

This did not work. What's missing?

```
import bpy
from math import *
two_pi = 2 * pi
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_xyz_function_surface(x_eq = "v", y_eq = "sin(two_pi*u)", z_eq = "cos(two_pi*u)")
```

Comment: The expectation that `two_pi` defined in your code above and passed via string to an operator is very unlikely to work.  Look in the system console most likely there is an error stating this.  Use `2 * pi` in expression.  With all add primitive objects creates a new one.

Comment: You were quite correct;  2 * pi worked fine ;  Thanks so much for your able assistance!